# Adobe Premiere wrong Aspect Ratio for 1080p video

Tags: premiere, video-editor, 1080p

I'm simply trying to setup a 1080p video. All the video sources are 1080p, here are the initial settings:

[image: Initial 1080p Settings]

However when I import and drag a new (and definitively confirmed 1080p) video to the timeline the preview shows a small black border on the left and right sides. I even removed the "Tile Safe Area" and "Action Safe Area" and the left/right black borders still appear.

The only thing I've noticed is that on the *project* panel is that the video info column shows the video at "0.75" [unknown units]. I am absolutely certain that the video is 1080p (1920x1080).

How do I fix this to get an *exact* one-to-one ratio for 1920x1080? The input videos are recorded via Open Broadcast Studio and the settings *seem* to be good. I've been trying to test things out to figure out what Premiere CS3 *does* support (very *very* little) to increase compatibility.

[image: Wrong Aspect Ratio]

Comment: It seems that your 30p video has been recorded with PAR=0.75, which makes it 1440x1080, not 1920x1080. Still, this should not preclude it to properly render to 16:9 DAR. I have no idea what Premiere does not like. Also, just wondering, where did you get 30.00 fps video? From a smartphone?

Comment: @RustyCore "The input videos are recorded via Open Broadcast Studio" - the videos measure at 1920x1080 when played in Media Player Classic *without* the black border; how would I make sure OBS shoots it in true 1920x1080 then?

Comment: First you need to verify the params of your video using something like MediaInfo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaInfo It may as well be 1920x1200 if this is native resolution for your monitor, then when resized to 1080 lines, you will get pillarboxing.